# Entity Framework and Crystal Reports

Tags: entity-framework, crystal-reports

As I understand it, Crystal Reports can use EntityFramework, is the correct?

I'd rather use Entity Framework instead using datasets.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Crystal reports support .net objects.  So you can pass an ienumerable of your entity framework object to a report instead of a dataset.